# Setting up Django with Apache got DB error - DatabaseError: DPI-1047

Tags: python, django, apache, cx-oracle

I am setting up Django in Apache 2.4, Suse 11.

Apache starts with no issue. If I don't put any DB connection info in Setting.py, the index page can be opened with no issue. When I put the DB info in, then tried to access the index page, I see below DB errors in Apache error output.

However, if I just run 'python', then 'import cx_Oracle as Database', there is no error.

I also put 'PassEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH' and 'PassEnv PATH' in httpd.conf.

Oracle Env variables are:

```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    export PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64:$PATH
```

Django version 1.10

Python version 2.7.13 64 bit

cx_Oracle 6.0

Let me know if any more detailed information from me could help. Thanks a lot!

```
    import cx_Oracle as Database
    DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Oracle Client library cannot be loaded:
    libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the one set of Oracle libraries on your machine, just use `ldconfig` and forget about trying to pass `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` through Apache.  I always found this a royal pain in Apache, since versions differ (some you use export, others not), sometimes you can set values in `httpd.conf`, other times it's better to put them in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`. It's all platform and version dependent.

You can use something like:

```
sudo sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Error went away after replacing cx_Oracle 6.0 with cx_Oracle 5.3......

Still not sure the root cause, I guess it has something to do with that cx_Oracle 6.0 might not be compatible with python 2.7?

Comment: cx_Oracle 6 works with Python 2 & 3.  There are even Wheels available for 2.7.  See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/